# Need help fixing placement of drawn paterns in console application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, console-application

So the user has a choice of 3 possible outputs:
- Draw a triangle
- Draw a rectangle
- Draw a house

I can draw all three but the output is not quiet right.

As you see in the code it draws a triangle but I need it to move more to the right.

```
if (keuze == 1)

            {

                int n = 4;



                int i, j, k = 0;

                for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)

                {



                    for (j = i; j < n; j++)

                    {

                        Console.Write(" ");

                    }



                    while (k != (2 * i - 1))

                    {

                        if (k == 0 || k == 2 * i - 2)

                            Console.Write("*");

                        else

                            Console.Write(" ");

                        k++;

                        ;

                    }

                    k = 0;





                    Console.WriteLine();

                }



                for (i = 0; i < 2 * n - 1; i++)

                {

                    Console.Write("*");

                }
Console.WriteLine();
}
```

[image: My Outcome]
[image: Expected outcome]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
if (true)
{

    int n = 4;

    int i, j, k = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (j = i; j < n; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }

        while (k != (2 * i - 1))
        {
            if (k == 0)     Console.Write("          "); //Added
            if (k == 0 || k == 2 * i - 2)
                Console.Write("*");
            else
                Console.Write(" ");

            k++;
        }

        k = 0;
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.Write("          ");  //Added
    for (i = 0; i < 2 * n - 1; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
    }

   Console.WriteLine();
}
```